# Регулярное выражение для поиска пар значений

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как можно разбить строку на пары int|float значений?
Пример строки:

```
1.2*1.0,2*0,0x1,1*3*5,4x2x4
```

На выходе хочу получить:

```
[
 [1.2,1.0],
 [2,0],
 [0,1],
 [1,3,5],
 [4,2,4],
]
```

Через 2 регекса получилось сделать (сначала бить по запятым, потом в цикле по * или x, а как сделать одним ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без цикла - никак. Да и зачем, и так сам разбор в одну строчку делается.

```
import re
s = "1.2*1.0,2*0,0x1,1*3*5,4x2x4"
lst = [re.split(r"[*x]", x) for x in s.split(",")]
```

Все числа приведены к *float*:

```
lst = [list(map(float, re.split(r"[*x]", x))) for x in s.split(",")]
```

Или если нужны именно числа конкретного типа:

```
lst = [list(map(lambda i: float(i) if "." in i else int(i), re.split(r"[*x]", x))) for x in s.split(",")]
```

Comment: Да. Я что-то подобное на go написал. Просто в регексе не силен и думал что вдруг можно без цикла

Comment: С одним регекспом как раз и проблема, что он в циклы не умеет. Если пытаться с подгруппами, то он соберёт только последние значения в каждой группе. Или можно распарсить все числа в планарный список (без иерархии). Хотя я не знаю, может в каком языке и есть какие навороты над стандартным регекспом, которые что-то такое могут. Но стандартный точно нет.

Comment: Спс. Ну я предпологал, но вдруг)) В любом случае спасибо за ответ